no wifi networks shown on kubuntu
i have wifi networks in my house but my computer kubuntu computer does not see them after i installed kubuntu (but if i switch back to ubuntu it sees the wifi networks).

Compare the output of the terminal command lsmod on the two systems. Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status.

does the wifi work in kubuntu?

You've provided no release details so we have no clues as to what you're running. The base of a Kubuntu system (or any flavor) is the same Ubuntu base as used by Ubuntu Desktop/Server, the only difference is kernel stack defaults which are set by install media for LTS releases (and third party drivers; these too can vary on release esp. with Kubuntu) but you've provided no details as to release, thus we can't know your issue or solution. If it works in Ubuntu, use that detail to make it work in Kubuntu as its the same base.

I have kubuntu 24.04 i installed additional companents and a medium install. I have the kubutu desktop.

it could not list wifi networks

But does it work in Kubuntu? Can you connect to Internet? If not you can try adding a Wifi through Network Connections by pressing the + and filling the info that should be there, If it works do not do that.

You can also check this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide

i dont know how to fill the wifi info but i can add a network
